# How powerful were Greek gods without their items?

Tags: greek, god-items

Many magical items Greek gods have are very powerful. But sometimes they hand them out like its Christmas.

**So how powerful are greek gods?**

Could, for example, Zeus still control weather without his lightning bolts? Were the items just a weak reflection of god power and modern fantasy gives them too much power?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The gods have powers of their own. As evidenced in the many hymns epics and poems.

Immortality

Transformation or shape shifting

Enhanced intelligence

The ability and powers to move from one place to another in an instant

Powers to manipulate animals to obey their commands

**Powers to manipulate the weather**

Powers to become invisible

Powers to create fantastic beings with supernatural powers

Their blood was a bright unearthly fluid called Ichor that had the power of producing new life

This is without their weapons .

So if you take away their weapons, they still have a lot of powers left.

source

Zeus • Facts and Information on Greek God of the Sky Zeus". Greek Gods & Goddesses.

Comment: So is it a misconception that the bolts had to be forged by Hephaestus?

Comment: Yes Hepheastus is rarely named. If they where forged it would be the 3 Kyklopes.
in some stories he has an infinte amount of lightning bolts that he carries around in a bucket or sack. But back to the point, if you see how many powers a god has if you take the weapon away, they are pretty damn powerfull.